# REST API using AngularJS issue

Tags: angularjs

I have a Products REST API that looks like below. The first part of the JSON helps to get the Products info and with-in the same data contains product_features with ID i.e., 4 and the id_feature_value i.e., 2943. The complete code is posted at the end.

```
{  
           "products":[  
              {  
                 "id":578,
                 "id_manufacturer":"24",
                 "available_later":"",
                 "associations":{  
                    "product_features":[  
                       {  
                          "id":"4",
                          "id_feature_value":"2943"
                       }
                    ]
                 }
              }
           ]
    }
```

At present I have created 3 services to get this information but there seems to some issue when it comes to print in the hybrid mobile app. It just prints the last item value in all the products. I tried using the sub ng-repeat but it throws angular iteration error.

I am creating hybrid mobile app out of my curiosity and not a developer (learning from forums) therefore I need some direction on 2 things

1. In the code where I am doing wrong causing it to print the last
   value of Features and Feature Values only instead actual
2. Is it recommended to use 3 services or should I
   combine into one considering this is a hybrid mobile app.

Appreciate.

```js
var gos_AppObject = angular.module('gosApp')

.run(function ($http, CacheFactory) {
    $http.defaults.cache = CacheFactory('defaultCache', {
        maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000, // Items added to this cache expire after 15 minutes
        cacheFlushInterval: 60 * 60 * 1000, // This cache will clear itself every hour
        deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive' // Items will be deleted from this cache when they expire
    });
})

/* 
  1st Service - Main Products and called once the device is ready
  For example.,
  
  Product: Coke Can (Pack of 6)
*/
.service('svc_Products', ['$http', 'CacheFactory', '$q', function ($http, CacheFactory, $q) {

    var baseURL = 'http://localhost/goslocal/api/';
    var ws_key = 'ws_key=SE7ELRQWM2BLDWL21ZI87D5NK615CW26';
    var resourceToAccess = 'products'
    var baseParams = '&display=full&sort=[id_DESC]&filter[active]=[1]&output_format=JSON';

    CacheFactory('productsList', {
        maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000, // Items added to this cache expire after 15 minutes
        cacheFlushInterval: 60 * 60 * 1000, // This cache will clear itself every hour.
        deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive' // Items will be deleted from this cache right when they expire.
    });

    return {

        ws_Product: function (id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var productsList = CacheFactory.get('productsList');

            // Now that control of inserting/removing from the cache is in our hands,
            // we can interact with the data in "dataCache" outside of this context,
            // e.g. Modify the data after it has been returned from the server and
            // save those modifications to the cache.
            if (productsList.get(id)) {
                deferred.resolve(productsList.get(id));
            }
            else {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: baseURL + '/' + resourceToAccess + '?' + ws_key + baseParams,
                    cache: true,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' } //or whatever type
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    productsList.put(id, data);
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    };

}])

/* 
  2nd Service - Product Features i.e., 4 which will give the Feature Name 
  For example.,
  
  Product: Coke Can (Pack of 6)
  Feature Name: Weight
  
*/
.service('svc_ProductsFeatures', ['$http', 'CacheFactory', '$q', function ($http, CacheFactory, $q) {

    var baseURL = 'http://localhost/goslocal/api/';
    var ws_key = 'ws_key=SE7ELRQWM2BLDWL21ZI87D5NK615CW26';
    var resourceToAccess = 'product_features'
    var baseParams = '&output_format=JSON';

    CacheFactory('productFeaturesList', {
        maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000, // Items added to this cache expire after 15 minutes
        cacheFlushInterval: 60 * 60 * 1000, // This cache will clear itself every hour.
        deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive' // Items will be deleted from this cache right when they expire.
    });

    return {
        ws_ProductFeatures: function (id, intFeatureID) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var productFeaturesList = CacheFactory.get('productFeaturesList');

            if (productFeaturesList.get(id)) {
                deferred.resolve(productFeaturesList.get(id));
            }
            else {

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: baseURL + '/' + resourceToAccess + '/' + intFeatureID + '?' + ws_key + baseParams,
                    cache: true,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' } //or whatever type
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    productFeaturesList.put(id, data);
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}])

/* 
  3rd Service Product Features Values - which will give the Product Feature Value
  For example.,
  
  Product: Coke Can (Pack of 6)
  Feature: Weight
  Feature Value: 6 x 300ml.
  
*/

.service('svc_ProductsFeatureValues', ['$http', 'CacheFactory', '$q', function ($http, CacheFactory, $q) {

    var baseURL = 'http://localhost/goslocal/api/';
    var ws_key = 'ws_key=SE7ELRQWM2BLDWL21ZI87D5NK615CW26';
    var resourceToAccess = 'product_feature_values'
    var baseParams = '&output_format=JSON';

    CacheFactory('productFeaturesValuesList', {
        maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000, // Items added to this cache expire after 15 minutes
        cacheFlushInterval: 60 * 60 * 1000, // This cache will clear itself every hour.
        deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive' // Items will be deleted from this cache right when they expire.
    });

    return {
        ws_ProductFeaturesValue: function (id, intFeatureValueID) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var productFeaturesValuesList = CacheFactory.get('productFeaturesValuesList');

            if (productFeaturesValuesList.get(id)) {
                deferred.resolve(productFeaturesValuesList.get(id));
            }
            else {

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: baseURL + '/' + resourceToAccess + '/' + intFeatureValueID + '?' + ws_key + baseParams,
                    cache: true,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' } //or whatever type
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    productFeaturesValuesList.put(id, data);
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);


/* 
  Products Display Contoller to display it in the front-end  
*/
gos_AppObject.controller('ProductsDisplayController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'svc_Products', 'svc_ProductsFeatures', 'svc_ProductsFeatureValues',
                        function ($scope, $filter, svc_Products, svc_ProductsFeatures, svc_ProductsFeatureValues)
{
    var productsImageURL = 'http://localhost/goslocal/api/images/products';

    $scope.productsLoader = {
        loading: false,
    };

    $scope.listOfProductFeatures = [];
    $scope.listOfProductFeaturesValue = [];
    $scope.status = null;
    $scope.listOfProducts = null;
    $scope.selectedProductID = null;

    /* to fetch the Main Products List by calling the Service */
    $scope.fn_ListOfProducts = function () {
        
        $scope.productsLoader.loading = true;
      
        var hasItems = 0;
        $scope.NoRecordPlaceholder = null;
        
        /* 
          Calling Web Service to fetch the Products from Server by passing the 
          unique key for CacheFactory to cache the data
        */
        svc_Products.ws_Product("key_ListOfProducts")
        .then(function (data) {

            if (data.products.length > 0) {
                hasItems = 1;
                $scope.listOfProducts = data.products;
            }
            else {
                hasItems = 0;
            };

            // Once the results are out, hide the Spinner
            $scope.productsLoader.loading = false;

            if (hasItems === 1) {
                $scope.NoRecordPlaceholder = true;
            }
            else {
                $scope.NoRecordPlaceholder = false;
            }
        });
    }

    /* to build the Image URL. Doesn't call any Service */
    $scope.buildImageURL = function (intProductID, intImageID) {
        return src = productsImageURL + '/' + intProductID + '/' + intImageID + '?ws_key=SE7ELRQWM2BLDWL21ZI87D5NK615CW26';
    };

    /* 
      Retrieve the Product Features
      For Example.,
      
      Product: Coke Can (Pack of 6)
      Feature Name: Weight
    */ 
    $scope.RetrieveProductFeatures = function (intFeatureID) {

        $scope.listOfProductFeatures = [];

        if (intFeatureID.length > 0) {

            svc_ProductsFeatures.ws_ProductFeatures("key_ListOfProductFeatures", intFeatureID)
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.listOfProductFeatures = data.product_feature;
            });
        }
        return;
    };
  
    /* 
      Retrieve the Product Features Values
      For Example.,
      
      Product: Coke Can (Pack of 6)
      Feature Name: Weight
      Feature Value: 6 x 330ml
    */
    $scope.RetrieveProductFeaturesValues = function(intFeaturesValueID) {

        $scope.listOfProductFeaturesValue = [];

        if (intFeaturesValueID.length > 0) {
            svc_ProductsFeatureValues.ws_ProductFeaturesValue("key_ListOfProductFeaturesValuess", intFeaturesValueID)
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.listOfProductFeaturesValue = data.product_feature_value;
            });
            return $scope.listOfProductFeaturesValue;
        }
    };

    function onDeviceReady() {
       $scope.fn_ListOfProducts();
    }

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

}]);
```

```html
<ons-row ng-controller="ProductsDisplayController">

                <div ng-show="productsLoader.loading" class="normalLoader padding5px">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" spin="true"></ons-icon>
                        <span class="generalText">Fetching data please wait...</span>
                </div>

                <div id="productContainer">

                    <ons-col ng-repeat="prods in listOfProducts | filter:{new: true}" class="productColumn">

                        <ul class="productUL">
                            <li style="background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center;">
                                <div style="position: relative;">
                                    <div id="productImageDIV">
                                        <img ng-src="{{buildImageURL(prods.id, prods.id_default_image)}}"
                                             alt="{{prods.name}}" class="productImage_List" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="productPriceDIV">
                                        <span class="productPrice_List">
                                            {{prods.price | currency}}
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="productName_List padding5px">{{prods.name}}</li>
                            <li class="productWeight_List padding5px"> 
                                <span ng-init="RetrieveProductFeatures(prods.associations.product_features[0].id)">
                                    <b>{{listOfProductFeatures.name}} : </b> 
                                </span>

                                <span ng-init="RetrieveProductFeaturesValues(prods.associations.product_features[0].id_feature_value)">
                                    {{listOfProductFeaturesValue.value}}
                                </span>
                                
                            </li>
                            <li class="padding5px">
                                <div>
                                    <button class="button tappable">
                                        <ons-icon icon="fa fa-shopping-cart"></ons-icon>
                                        <span>Add to Cart</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="button button--light tappable">
                                        <ons-icon icon="fa fa-heart"></ons-icon>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </ons-col>

                </div>
                
                <div ng-if="NoRecordPlaceholder===false" class="padding5px" style="width: 100%;">
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <ons-icon icon="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-4x"></ons-icon>
                        <br />
                        <span style="font-size: 25px; text-align:center; width: 100%;" class="center">
                            No New Arrivals, check back again.
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </ons-row>
```